# "Zu hause" vs "Nach hause"

Tags: word-choice

My girlfriend just said:

> Ich hoffe, er kommt bald nach Hause

If it had been me, I would have used *zu Hause*. Is she right? What are the differences?

Comment: Did the subject of your conversation include sexual climaxes?

Comment: @Carsten: LOL :D Upvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Nach Hause gehen" means "to go home" and "zu Hause" means "at home".

"Zu" is for location and "nach" for destination.