# zu haus oder nach haus

Tags: preposition

I found this sentence "Silvia stieg aus dem Taxi und ging **zu** Jochens Haus." in a short story book. Wouldn't it be better to replace **zu** with **nach**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Zu hause" vs "Nach hause"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20779/zu-hause-vs-nach-hause)

Comment: Why do you think that using *nach* instead of *zu* would be better here (which is actually not the case)?

Comment: Because a movement from one position (Taxi) to another one (Haus) occurred. As mentioned before in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20779/zu-hause-vs-nach-hause.

Comment: It seems in English one should use "went to the house" which should be "nach Hause". Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome on German.SE. Please include all clarification from you into your question. So all your thinking why what how. Makes it possible to find the answer you seek.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, in my opinion, since the other questions seem to be about the contrast between *zu Hause* and *nach Hause*, whereas this one is about *nach Hause* versus *zur Post, zum Amt, zu Jochens Haus*.

Comment: @ETeddy The difference is: *ging zum Haus* = *went to the house* whereas *ging nach Hause* = *went home*.

Answer (score 3):

*Nach* is used to indicate a direction with names of cities, countries and the like when they do not have an article.

> Wir fahren **nach** Paris, Frankreich, Bayern.

*In* is used with names where the article is obligatory.

> Wir fahren **in** **die** Schweiz, **in** **die** Bourgogne.

*Nach* is also used as a fixed expression with *Hause* to indicate movement toward someone's home. As a fixed expression, *Hause* must occur alone and cannot be accompanied by any other word (e.g. no article, not prenominal genitive such as *Jochens*).

> Ihr könnt **nach Hause** fahren.

*Zu* as a directional preposition can be combined with nouns indicating people or places. In this case, an article must be present.

> Ich muss **zum** Arzt, **zur** Post, **zu Jochens** Haus.

The final piece of the puzzle is that a prenominal genitive such as *Jochens* is equivalent to a definite article. Therefore, *Jochens Haus* fits *zu* but not *nach* for the reason mentioned above.

With names, no article is required.

> Geh doch **zu** Dr. Piegsa.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd just like to add that in antiquated language (until maybe 100 years ago), you could indeed say things like _wir fahren nach der Schweiz_ (and perhaps even _Ich ging nach der Post_, but I'm not quite sure about that).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar, but has different meanings:

zu Hause → at home
nach Hause → home (direction)
das Zuhause → the home

zu Jochens Haus → to Jochen's house/home

While the two are interchangeable in English they're not in German. In colloquial German you might even say zu Haus, nach Haus, because the -e at the end is actually a historic form and already dropped in many other words (e.g. am Grabe → am Grab, zu Gemüte → zu Gemüt).

Comment: Imho, to Jochen's home is wrong. Jochens Haus sagt erst mal nur, dass Jochen Eigentümer/Besitzer ist, nicht, dass er da wohnt. Das lässt "Jochen's house' ebenfalls offen.

Comment: Das schließt sich nicht aus. Wenn ich sage „wir gehen zu Omas Haus”, dann würde ich das interpretieren als den Ort, wo Oma auch wohnt.

Comment: Sicher schließt ihr Wohnen nicht aus, dass ihr das Haus gehört. Wenn es ihr gehört und dort 3 weitere Haushalte wohnen, ist es immer noch ihr Haus. Aber wenn sie dort wohnt, ihr das Haus aber nicht gehört, sagt man doch einfach "Wir gehen zur Oma." Aber "zu Omas Haus" sagt man auch, wenn sie nicht darin wohnt.

Comment: Nö. Meine Oma hat zu Lebzeiten in einem Mietshaus gewohnt, ihre Cousine auch. Wir sagten oft, wir gehen zu Omas Haus, auch wenn es ihr nicht gehört hatte.